# nodejs/express include local js file

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

Here is my current folder structure

```
css
   app.css
js
  app.js
node-modules
index.html
node-server.js
package.json
```

The node-server is hosting `index.html`, but I can't figure out how to get the `app.js` and `app.css` files to get loaded.

`index.html` loads them with:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/app.css"/>
```

Here is the error message:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2http://localhost:3000/css/app.css Failed to load resource: the server 
responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I know i need to require or load module or something, just can't figure out what.

Thanks

Comment: So, uh, where's your node.js server code?

Comment: You must add in your express app something like `app.use(express.static('css'));` and then refer to it in html with `href="/app.css"` but it would be better to put `js` and `css` folder into `public` folder and then add this to your express app code: `app.use(express.static('public'));`

Comment: wow, duh!  I forgot about that part @TomaszKasperek.  Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

**Reason**
Node.Js does not server static content on it's own, routes has to defined for serving static content via Node.

**Solution(Manual)**:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    app = express();

app.get('/index.html',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html')); 
});

app.get('/css/app.css',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/css/app.css')); 
});

app.get('/js/app.js',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/js/app.js')); 
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

**Better Solution**:

Directory Structure:

```
public
 css
   app.css
 js
  app.js
 index.html
```

CODE:

```
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    app = express();

// Express Middleware for serving static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('index.html');
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 10):

As [Tomasz Kasperek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3114851/tomasz-kasperek) pointed out, you need to let Express know that you intend to host these files in a static directory. This is technically called [defining static middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.built-in).

This should look something like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// first parameter is the mount point, second is the location in the file system
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
```

It's super simple and I suggest you go the route of making some sort of `public` folder, rather than bothering to make specific files and folders static.

Then the files would simply be referenced like so from the root `index.html`:

```
<link href="public/css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: You have to make sure you include express as so:  

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

otherwise it will tell you express is not defined and you will want to punch babies.

Comment: I feel like that should be a given, but I've added it for completeness. Good catch!

Comment: It wasn't a given for me, the example I was referencing had me doing var app = require('express')() I think, and it was giving me grief.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by using this syntax

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

Copy the css and js files under the 'public' directory
and then add the reference in the index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
//we are in ./utils/dbHelper.js, here we have some helper functions
function connect() {
  // connect do db...
}

function closeConnection() {
  // close connection to DB...
}

//let's export this function to show them to the world outside
module.exports = {
  connect(),
  closeConnection()
};

// now we are in ./main.js and we want use helper functions from dbHelper.js
const DbHelper = require('./utils/dbHelper'); // import all file and name it DbHelper
DbHelper.connect(); // use function from './utils/dbHelper' using dot(.)

// or we can import only chosen function(s)
const {
  connect,
  closeConnection
} = require('./utils/dbHelper');
connect(); // use function from class without dot
```