# Change dropdown options in HTML form based on another dropdown's selection in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, forms, express, validation

I have a Node.js application consisting of the following file system:

```
public
   elegant-aero.css
   stadium-wallpaper.jpg
   team-results.html
   public.js
app.js
teamresults.mustache
```

Through an HTML form, I want to populate the options of a dropdown menu based on the user's selected option from another dropdown menu. HTML is below:

```
<form>
   <label for="selectLeague">
    <span>National League:</span>
         <select id="selectLeague" name="leagueCode">
             <option style="display:none;"></option>
             <option value="SP1">Spanish La Liga</option>
             <option value="E0">English Premier League</option>
             <option value="D1">German Bundesliga</option>
             <option value="F1">French Ligue 1</option>
             <option value="I1">Italian Serie A</option>
             <option value="P1">Portuguese Primeira Liga</option>
             <option value="N1">Dutch Eredivisie</option>
             <option value="SC0">Scottish Premier League</option>
         </select>
   </label>
   <label for="selectTeam">
   <span>Team Name:</span>
       <select id="selectTeam" name="teamName">
           <option>Choose a team:</option>
           <!-- populated after user makes a selection on league -->
       </select>
   </label>
   <label>
    <span></span> <input  type="submit" value="Submit">
   </label>
</form>
```

There are simple ways that this can be accomplished with just JavaScript through client-side rendering. For example:
[Dynamically Populating Drop down list from selection of another drop down value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30232146/dynamically-populating-drop-down-list-from-selection-of-another-drop-down-value)

However, I absolutely cannot get this to work with Node.js (sever-side). Following the example in the link above, I created a JavaScript file called public.js and put it in the public directory. The JavaScript file contains the following dummy code:

```
// Hard code all teams by their leagues, as a test
const teamsByLeague = {
    SP1: [
        "Real Madrid",
        "Barcelona"
    ],
    E0: [
        "Chelsea",
        "Arsenal"
    ]
}

function updateTeamSelection(leagueCode) {
    if (leagueCode.length == 0) document.getElementById("selectTeam").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var teamOptions = "";
        for (teamIndex in teamsByLeague[leagueCode]) {
            teamOptions += "<option>" + teamsByLeague[leagueCode][teamIndex] + "</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("selectTeam").innerHTML = teamOptions;
    }
}
```

I updated the HTML file to contain this line on the league selection dropdown menu:

```
<label for="selectLeague" onChange="updateTeamSelection(this.value);">
```

And added this in the body of the HTML document:

```
<script src="public.js"></script>
```

And lastly, following an advice I saw in the following StackOverflow page:

[nodejs/express include local js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29357305/nodejs-express-include-local-js-file)

I added the following line to app.js:

```
 app.get('/public.js',function(req,res){
   res.sendFile('public.js');
});
```

Nevertheless, after all of this, when changing the selection on the league dropdown menu, I still get the error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: updateTeamSelection is not defined
> onchange

Not exactly sure what am I missing. Any help is massively appreciated!

Comment: The label is not gonna change when you select something in the dropdown, the select element will !! Move `onChange="updateTeamSelection(this.value);"` to the select element like so `<select id="selectLeague" name="leagueCode" onchange="updateTeamSelection(this.value);">` also the `onchange` is lowercase  so NOT like this `onChange`

Comment: I made the change:
<select id="selectLeague" name="leagueCode" onchange="updateTeamSelection(this.value);">

However, the error Uncaught ReferenceError: updateTeamSelection is not defined onchange still persists.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="selectid">
        <option>name</option>
    </select>
    <select id="secondselectid"></select>
    <script>
        var selectid = document.getElementById('selectid')
        var secondselectid = document.getElementById('secondselectid')
        var fetcheddata = false

        function adddatatosecondone (data) {
            secondselectid.innerHTML = "";
            data.forEach(i => {
                var option = document.createElement('option')
                var text = document.createTextNode(i)
                option.appendChild(text)
                secondselectid.appendChild(option)
            });
        }

        selectid.addEventListener(onchange, () => {
            fetch("path to your online server", {method: 'GET'})
            .then(data => {
                return data.json()
            }).then(data => {
                fetcheddata = data
                adddatatosecondone(data)
            })//method is of your choice if your server receives post or get whatever
        })

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and you have to make a server with nodejs and on request by the above html you have to send a json response if you are using expressn you can send this with res.json();

Comment: Could you explain how selectid.addEventListener is actually getting any data from the current selected element in the first dropdown menu?

Comment: @Charlie Brown to get the selected item value you need to add a value attribute in all your <option> tag and to get the value of the selected option you can call selectid.value property

Comment: @Charlie Brown selectid.value will return you the value of the selected person